# File owner changed when showing NSPopover

Tags: macos, cocoa, xib, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

This looks really strange to me

Once i add a NSPopover and it's contentVC to the Nib (file owner is set right to myVC) and right **AFTER** triggering

```
[self.sliderPopover showRelativeToRect:rect ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

All mi bindings and action bound to FileOwner(myVC) are (re)bound to the Popovers content VC and i'am getting lot's of

```
Could not connect the action testValueChanged: to target of class SliderPopoverViewController
```

As the Popovers contentVC, doesn't have the corresponding path

**Why is this happening?**

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

when i do

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [self.sliderPopover.contentViewController view];

}
```

**the same problem occurs, so it's definitely related to loading of the contentVC**

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing the name from 
SliderPopoverViewController.xib to __SliderPopoverViewController.xib did helpe, but i still don't understand why (and in second place, i don't understand, why the __SliderPopoverViewController was loaded after name change (as it doesn't match the name of the class))

**So is this all some weird bug?**

Answer (score 0):

Must have been some bug, renaming the

`SliderPopoverViewController.xib` to `__SliderPopoverViewController.xib` did helped